# Is it possible to type-hint a compiled regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, type-hinting

I would like to use autocompletion for a pre-compiled and stored list of regular expressions, but it doesn't appear that I can import the _sre.SRE_Pattern class, and I can't programmatically feed the obtained type from type() to a comment of the format # type: classname or use it for a return -> classname style hint

Is there a way to explicitly import a class from the _sre.c thing?

Comment: I think __Regex might be a built in name that could accomplish this.

Comment: Have you considered using https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.re

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You should use [`typing.Pattern` and `typing.Match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Pattern) which were specifically added to the typing module to accommodate this use case.

Example:

```
from typing import Pattern, Match
import re

my_pattern = re.compile("[abc]*")  # type: Pattern[str]
my_match = re.match(my_pattern, "abbcab")  # type: Match[str]
print(my_match)
```

Comment: It doesn't look like pycharm understands the typing module completely yet, but it does appear this is how it is supposed to work.

Comment: Pycharm certainly complains  and complains that the Type of an re.compile is _Regex (and not typing.Pattern or typing.Pattern[str])

Comment: Be aware that `typing` was added in 3.5, so your code will throw runtime errors on 3.4 or older.

Comment: @EdwardNedHarvey -- you can get around that by installing the `typing` module via pip. It's available as a backport for Python 2.7 and 3.3+.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 [`__Regex`](https://github.com/JetBrains/python-skeletons/blob/95ad24b666e475998e5d1cc02ed53a2188036167/re.py#L121) appears to be an internal "skeleton" in PyCharm which is applied automatically when PyCharm can figure out that you have a result of `re.compile`, but I don't see any way of actually using it as a type hint in source code to enable code completion.

Comment: @Michael0x2a, according to the docs you linked to for Match and Pattern were deprecated in 3.9.  The documentation points to <https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#generic-alias-type> and type hints like `re.Match[str]`. Still +1 since this answer got me to the ultimate solution. Will you update the answer?

Comment: I am using ruff linter and it's says you need to use "from re import Pattern" because of import from typing is deprecated